# How do i make a media tweet using google-apps-script?

Tags: api, twitter, google-apps-script, twitter-oauth

I am using :

> https://script.google.com/d/MKvHYYdYA4G5JJHj7hxIcoh8V4oX7X1M_/edit?usp=drive_web

as my twitter library. And i am trying to send a media tweet by grabbing the image from https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random , well i am getting media upload response as below :

> Upload media success. Response was {"media_id":710312931842371584,"media_id_string":"710312931842371584","size":10318,"expires_after_secs":86400,"image":{"image_type":"image/jpeg","w":200,"h":300}}

And my script looks like this:

```
function tweetImage()
{
   var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(),
        twit = new Twitter.OAuth(props);

    if (twit.hasAccess()) { 
      var image = twit.grabImage("https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random");
      var incomming = twit.uploadMedia(image);
      var mediaId = JSON.stringify(incomming.media_id);

      twit.sendTweet(subash,{media_id_string:mediaId},null);
    } 

}
```

Now how do i use incoming **media_id_string** to make media tweet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maintain the Twitter library that you're using.  Twitter requires that media IDs be sent with the `media_ids` property (in a comma-separated list) when posting a Tweet.  Here's how it looks when I send a Tweet for the [@swagspiration](https://twitter.com/swagspiration) bot:

```
twit.sendTweet(
  tweet.text.replace(/@/g, "."), //remove @-mentions.  Bad juju to @mention with bots.
  { media_ids: mediaobj.media_id_string }
);
```

Hope this helps.